# Pytorch: Appending tensors like a list

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a dataset with random data like the following:

```
data = torch.normal(0, 1, size = (1, 3))
dataset = torch.tensor(data.T).float()
print(dataset)
#tensor([[-2.1445],
#        [-1.3322],
#        [-0.6355]])
```

And now I want to simulate Brownian motions which are started in the 1-dimensional points given by the dataset up to a certain time `t` with a step size `dt`. In the example above, the desired output should look like:

```
#tensor([[-2.1445, -2.1035, -2.1022],
#        [-1.3322, -1.3121, -1.3210],
#        [-0.6355, -0.6156, -0.5999]])
```

for `dt = .01` and `t = .02`. That is, the first dimension corresponds to `t = 0`, the second to `t = .01`, the third to `t = .02` and so on in general. Here is what I tried:

```
def brownian_motion(x, t, dt):
    k = int(t / dt)
    path = [x]
    path.append(x)

    for i in range(k):
        xi = torch.normal(torch.zeros(x.shape), torch.ones(x.shape))
        x += numpy.sqrt(dt) * xi
        path.append(x)
```

However, this gives me a list of several tensors of size 3. But what I need want to return is a tensor of size (k + 1, 3) (assuming the dataset size is 3). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html), that concatenates tensor along a dimension. You also do not need to append `x` to path since it's already initiated with x inside.

In addition, you should not use in-place operators, since your tensors will share the same memory (resulting in a list of tensors with identical values, and you will not be able to track down the step by step motion). Instead, you can copy the tensor or create a new one.

Here is my version of your method returning a `(len(dataset), k+1)` tensor.

```py
def brownian_motion(x, t, dt):
    k = int(t / dt)
    path = [x]

    for _ in range(k):
        xi = torch.normal(torch.zeros(x.shape), torch.ones(x.shape))
        path.append(path[-1] + numpy.sqrt(dt) * xi)

    return torch.cat(path, dim=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `x` in this case is your `dataset` tensor which is of shape `(3,1)`.

You want to combine the outputs with `torch.stack`, which stacks tensors together along a new axis.

```py
def brownian_motion(x, t, dt):
    k = int(t / dt)
    path = [x]
    path.append(x)

    for i in range(k):
        xi = torch.normal(torch.zeros(x.shape), torch.ones(x.shape))
        x += np.sqrt(dt) * xi # you may want to replace this line with `x = path[-1] + np.sqrt(dt) * xi`
        path.append(x)
        
    return torch.stack(path).squeeze()

data = torch.normal(0, 1, size = (1, 3))
dataset = torch.tensor(data.T).float()

out = brownian_motion(dataset, 0.02, 0.01)
out.shape
> torch.Size([4, 3])
```

To explain the final line:

- we have `path` which is a list of tensors of shape `(3, 1)`
- we compute `torch.stack(path)`, which stacks the tensors in `path` along a new axis, giving a tensor of shape `(k+2, 3, 1)`. Note that this is `k+2` rather than your desired `k+1` because the input `x` tensor is added to `path` twice (`path = [x]`, `path.append(x)`) - not sure if this is intended or a bug.
- we call `.squeeze()` on the stack result to remove the unit axis at the end, giving a result of size `(k+2, 3)`